# How to close a popout window using selenium

Tags: selenium

I'm very new to Selenium and need to be able to close a popout window. I can get it open, but I can't seem to make the code recognize there's a new window. I've tried every code I've found in all of these questions, with parents, and handles and I'm just more confused. My skills are very basic, but any help would be appreciated. The pop up window that opens has a close button, and I have the name for it to click, but I really need the simplest way for the code to recognize the new window before it gets to the close button.

Any help is appreciated!

Going to try to add the code here.

```
   owd.findElement(By.xpath(vath)).click(); //Click ATH button
   System.out.println("ATH Report opened"); 

   //#1
   //owd.get(vURL2);
   //System.out.println("popout is opened"); 

   //#2
   //String parentWindowHandler = owd.getWindowHandle(); // Store your parent window
   //String subWindowHandler = null;

   //#3
   //Select handles = (Select) owd.getWindowHandles(); // get all window handles
   //Iterator<String> iterator = ((Set<String>) handles).iterator();
   //while (iterator.hasNext()){
   //    subWindowHandler = iterator.next();
   //}
   //owd.switchTo().window(subWindowHandler); // switch to popup window
                                               // perform operations on popup

   //owd.switchTo().window(parentWindowHandler);  // switch back to parent window

   //#4
   //owd.switchTo()).handle().accept();

   //#5       
   //String winHandle = owd.getWindowHandle(); //Get current window handle.
   //for(String windowsHandle : owd.getWindowHandles()) {
      //  owd.switchTo().window(windowsHandle); //Iterate to the new window handle.
   /*
   Do any action on window or just close it.
   */

  // owd.switchTo().window(winHandle); //Switch to original window.


   //#6
   owd.switchTo().window(vwindow);


   owd.findElement(By.xpath(vclose)).click(); //Click Close button
   System.out.println("Close button clicked");
```

Comment: So, please show us what you have tried. Probably we can help you find bugs, if any, in the code you have written

Comment: As per what Saifur says you need to provide code so we can see what you're trying to do and advise. Help yourself so we can help you. :-)

Comment: Here is my code. The Report opens in the popout, and that's where it fails. I've tried several things for the name of the popout-Title, URL, filename-as far as I know, none of them work. I've commented out each attempt when it doesn't work so I can track them.

Comment: owd.findElement(By.xpath(vath)).click(); //Click ATH button
       System.out.println("ATH button clicked"); 
       
       //#1
       //owd.get(vURL2);
       //System.out.println("popout is opened"); 
       
       //#2
       //String parentWindowHandler = owd.getWindowHandle(); // Store your parent window
       //String subWindowHandler = null

Comment: I don't know how to fix the formatting on this screen, sorry. I've never used this forum before.

Comment: //#3
       //Select handles = (Select) owd.getWindowHandles(); // get all window handles
       //Iterator<String> iterator = ((Set<String>) handles).iterator();
       //while (iterator.hasNext()){
       //    subWindowHandler = iterator.next();
       //}
       //owd.switchTo().window(subWindowHandler); // switch to popup window
                                                   // perform operations on popup

       //owd.switchTo().window(parentWindowHandler);  // switch back to parent window
       
       //#4
       //owd.switchTo()).handle().accept();

Comment: //#5       
       //String winHandle = owd.getWindowHandle(); //Get current window handle.
       //for(String windowsHandle : owd.getWindowHandles()) {
          //  owd.switchTo().window(windowsHandle); //Iterate to the new window handle.
       /*
       Do any action on window or just close it.
       */

      // owd.switchTo().window(winHandle); //Switch to original window.
       
       
       //#6
       owd.switchTo().window(vwindow);

       owd.findElement(By.xpath(vclose)).click(); //Click Close button
       System.out.println("Close button clicked");

Answer (score 0):

you need to switch to active window/popup alert/frame firstly:

```
driver.SwitchTo().Window(<windowname>)
driver.SwitchTo().Frame("iFrmLinks")
```

and to close as allways.

if you are talk about alerts:

```
driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
alert.accept();
```